# How to read ASCII file with variable delimiters?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to read ASCII files as the one below. Each item in a row is separated by some delimiter like comma or colon.

```
ROUND    079675882    1446320661365001Y00000   000M   8019721193     ROUND       6613-144632                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             000875                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 <EOR>
ROUND    079675882    1446320661365001Y10000   S10    ROUND    875079675882    144632                11180524180525XYZSONS1   21130     8019721193  ROUND    1805241300000000000087500000000180524144632                XYZSONS COMPANIES, LLC          9 0091372096500NATIONAL SERVICES CENTER           P.O. BOX 29093                     AZAD            AZ85038    BUGASON A SUB. OF ALBERTSONS, LLC          9 0091372096613                                                                                                                                 <EOR>
ROUND    079675882    1446320661365001Y20000   S11    Boundaris GHBC                     3649 F Public Court            Cian           ID83642    HELTHY HEALTHCARE LLC 9 079675882                                       1190 OMEGA DR.                     MANGO         PA15205    0100BDDARYL BHINDI       2088874065     TENOT USED             02180605GEN                                                                                                                           TRUCK                                               0258220026501          <EOR>
ROUND    079675882    1446320661365001Y30000   S12            0000034CA00000178LB00000000000000000000000000181450000000000000NPO BOX 826614 - ABS AP             UGANDA, PA                   PPM  018889974498GEN                              GEN                              GENZZ1                                                         GENZZ2                                                                                                     GEN GEN GENZZ3    GENZZ4    GENZZ5                                                                                             <EOR>
```

I use the code, but that does not work:

```
val DataReaderDF = spark.read
   // i am not sure if this delimiter is ok or not
   // to be used in my ASCII file input source
  .option("delimiter", "\r\n\r\n")  
  .option("header", false)
  .text("/example_data/InputFile/20180524_840860__PO_D20180524130814_TXT")
```

How to load such datasets?

Comment: I don't see the requirement used in the sample, i.e. _"Each item in a row is separated by some delimiter like comma or colon."_ Is this used or is the sample incorrect?

Comment: That is the problem there is no delimiter in this file and i need to parse it

Comment: Ah, so that's why you used multiple separators in `option("delimiter", "\r\n\r\n")` which I think is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to deal with such a file is to load it as a text file (using `text` data source) and `split` the lines by the whitespaces or whatever separator the file uses, e.g.

```
val entireFileAsSingleColumn = spark.read.text("tab-separated.txt")
scala> entireFileAsSingleColumn.printSchema
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

val splitLines = entireFileAsSingleColumn.withColumn("split", split('value, "\\s+"))
scala> splitLines.printSchema
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- split: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

// use as many $"split" as a line has elements
val solution = splitLines.select($"split"(0) as "round", $"split"(1) as "num")
scala> solution.show
+-----+---------+
|round|      num|
+-----+---------+
|ROUND|079675882|
|ROUND|079675882|
|ROUND|079675882|
|ROUND|079675882|
|     |     null|
+-----+---------+
```